Correlation and $z$-Transformation for Vectors With Correlation Structure
Consider a set of $p$ pairs $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_p,y_p)$, the sample correlation coefficient is
$$r=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^p (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^p (x_i-\bar{x})^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^p (y_i-\bar{y})^2}}$$
When discussing $z$ transformation, the usual setting is this: the pairs are assumed to be iid and originate form a bivariate normal distribution $F$. Under this setting (and assuming $cor(x_i,y_i)=\rho$), we get the approximate distribution
$$z\sim\mathcal{N}\left( \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+\rho}{1-\rho}\right), \frac{1}{\sqrt{p-3}} \right)$$
Up to here it's very common. According to Hawkins (1989), the bivariate normality assumption can be relaxed to be "$F$ has finite first four moments". Which is nice but not very helpful for the following cases of dependency:

The pairs are not i.i.d but rather have some dependency structure (we can call this "usual dependency"). This is interesting in general, but not the focal point of this question.

The data is not $p$ samples from a bivariate function but rather two samples from a $p$-dimensional function. That is, some correlation structure $\Sigma_{p\times p}$ might exist between $x_i$ entries.


The latter point might sound odd, but it can be easily exemplified:

Given a class of $p$ students, math teacher and French teacher need to rank the students by their behavior (1=best, $p$=worst, only discrete values, each value used once)

Given a class of $p$ students, English teacher and French teacher need to pick $k$ students who should get a stipend (1=stipend, 0=no stipend)

The coefficient vectors of two linear regression models (e.g. LASSO and Ridge) trained on the same data


In each of the cases, there is some relation between the different entries of $x$ (in example 1, the value picked for $x_i$ affects the possible values for $x_j$; in example 2, the choice of $k$ "1" entries forces the rest to be "0"). We would like to assess the level of agreement between $x,y$ by using $z$-transformation on the sample correlation. Our null hypothesis here is not necessarily $H_0:\rho=0$ but rather $\rho\ge 0.5$ (for example).
What do we know about the behavior of $z$ statistic under such settings?
